# Cordova windows 10 mobile app text scaling will change application font size issue

Tags: cordova, plugins, windows-10-universal, windows-10-mobile

I have created window 10 mobile application using cordova. I have a signed build for windows 10 mobile app. App is behaving very well when text scale is minimum. But whenever I go to settings->Ease Of Access -> More options -> Text Scaling, and change text scaling, device text font size getting changed. But due to this device text scaling settings, my application font size getting change and app will get distorted view. Is there any solution or plugin available to disable device text scaling for windows 10 mobile app? It's working fine with windows 8 phone. But creating issue in windows 10 mobile app.

Comment: UWP uses  effective pixels for development, currently there is no effective way for UWP(JS) to reverse the Text Scaling. And it is also not recommended to do so.

Comment: Thanks Elvis for your reply. Do we have any work around, because for me, text is getting overlapped. Can we disable the device settings? Because for windows 8 its working fine, but for UWP facing issues. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please post your html overlapped codes? I'll see what I can do.